# Exception in thread "main" java.lang. NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

encoutered the above problem: I want to display information of student. i created parent class People and inherited to class Student.

```
public class ListPeople {
protected String name;

List<ListPeople> listPeople = new ArrayList<ListPeople>();

 public void setName() {

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

         ListPeople people = new ListPeople();   //object of parent class

         System.out.print("Enter your Name: ");
         people.name = input.nextLine();

         listPeople.add(people);
     }
 }

 public class ListStudent extends ListPeople {
 public void getName() {
    for (ListPeople people : listPeople) {
        System.out.print("Name of Student:");
        System.out.print(people.name);

    }
  }
 }
  public class ListMain {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListPeople people = new ListStudent();
    people.setName();

    ListStudent student = new ListStudent();
    student.getName();
}
}
```

i have to create two kinds of objects student and teachers. i inherit method setName to input but override getName in child clas to display respective names.

Comment: Can you provide the full exception message?

Comment: List.ListStudent.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. On my computer your code doesn’t compile. You cannot have `public static void main()` in a non-static inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes:

- you can't define more than one public class within a file in java
- This will create the new instance of ListStudent type it means your listPeople is empty initially.

  ListStudent student = new ListStudent();
     student.getName();

//Little modified

```
import java.util.*;

class ListPeople {
    protected String name;

    protected List<ListPeople> listPeople = new ArrayList<ListPeople>();

    public void setName() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

            ListPeople people = new ListPeople();   //object of parent class

            System.out.print("Enter your Name: ");
            people.name = input.nextLine();

            listPeople.add(people);
        }   

    }   

    public void getName(){

    }   

}

class ListStudent extends ListPeople {
    public void getName() {
        for (ListPeople people : listPeople) {
        System.out.print("Name of Student:");
        System.out.println(people.name);

        }   
    }   
}


public class ListMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListPeople people = new ListStudent();
        people.setName();
        people.getName();
    }   
}
```